# How to scan multiple directories with clamav

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clamav

I know how to scan one directory:

```
clamscan -r /home
```

but for the life of me I cannot seem to get multiple directories working and I cannot seem to Google this simple problem.

I have tried:

```
clamscan -r /home /otherdir
clamscan -r /home,/otherdir
```

to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the list of folders/files in a text file and pass it to clamscan using -f.

[Example](https://askubuntu.com/a/965039/148011):
`clamscan -r -z -i --bell --file-list=/home/nav/ClamScanTheseFolders.txt`

Comment: Aha, I see it on the man page now, seemed to overlook the `f` option thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
DIRTOSCAN="/home /var/spool /bin /sbin";
for S in ${DIRTOSCAN}; do
  clamscan -ri "$S" >> "$LOGFILE";
done
```

Credit: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-clamav-to-scan-and-notify-virus-and-malware/

Answer (score 2):

Note that currently in Debian 10, I can scan two directories by simply passing them both at the command line:

```
clamscan -irv /root/test1/ /root/test2/
```

The switches stand for:

- v: verbose, to get the output
- i: infected only
- r: recursive

This will result in:

```
Scanning /root/test1/a.php
Scanning /root/test2/b.php

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6849828
Engine version: 0.102.2
Scanned directories: 2
Scanned files: 2
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 15.759 sec (0 m 15 s)
```

Comment: I can confirm that works now indeed with as many directories as you wish. This should become the new accepted answer.